# Publisher costs to publish a book

Tags: data-request, finance, research, publications

I am looking for a data set listing publisher costs to publish a book. There can be many types of costs, ranging from editing costs to marketing costs and print/server costs.

I am interested in both textbooks and research books.  I am mostly interested in the fields of computer science and maths, and English-speaking venues, but I am curious about other fields and languages as well.